# Fastest way to find certain value of variable of object in object array

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` of custom objects I called `Questions`. These `Questions` contain the question, a unique `ID`, and an `ArrayList` of `Answers`. Now I'm trying to search for the question with a specific unique `ID`. This is what I'm currently doing but I'm worried this might take too long for a big list, so I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this.

```
public Question getQuestion(String idLookingFor) {
    for (Question question : questions) {
        if (question.getId().equals(idLookingFor))
            return question;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `HashMap` for storing the information about `ID as key` and `Question as value`. I am assuming, `ID` is stored as `Interger`.

```
Map<Integer, Question> map = new HashMap<>();
```

The `Map` will provide you `O(1)` time complexity for searching the question.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I forgot about `Map`!

Comment: Yes, storing in both containers, surprising (List and Map) at first look, but give fast information: order what item was added (list) and fast search by key via Map. Use such pattern once in a month, id works goog.